# Protocol Buffers vs Thrift: which is quicker to build server / client with?

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio, protocol-buffers, thrift

So we want to build a server/client system in C++, and I am unclear whether Google protocol buffers or thrift will get us a working prototype more quickly. We want to use TCP sockets as the communication layer, for communication over a local subnet (not over the wide internet). It will run on Linux/OS X/Windows.

We mostly need simple async message passing in each direction, but we might want RPC-style responses in the future. Most of our messages are small, but several will have large payloads of about 100k-500k (those would just be a big opaque buffer accompanying a message if we had to call them out in the IDL).

I know we want the message descriptor/marshalling/unmarshalling that both of them offer, but I'm unclear about the other pieces needed to most quickly build a working server/client.

Am I right in gathering that thrift supplies implementations for TCP/IP socket communication to send and receive the messages, while Protocol Buffers only deals with the marshalling layer and doesn't know anything about sockets?

If that is indeed the case, then with Protocol Buffers, you'd have to write a mini-protocol on top of it to wrap some headers and/or footers around the messages to identify where one stops and the next one begins as the come over the socket (and the more difficult issue of resyncing if something's longer/shorter than expected). Are there open source packages that supply these layers (preferably using `boost::asio`)?

Comment: this is [off topic and why](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: http://floatingsun.net/articles/thrift-vs-protocol-buffers/

Comment: Jarrod, I think it's a specific and reasonable question that others would encounter: "do thrift or PB have the necessary pieces to build a basic network server?", followed by "if not, how do you best fill in the missing pieces?"  The question actually came after reading the various comparisons out there, including the one Thomas suggests, which doesn't address this point.

If the second part is too open-ended for your taste, you can just answer the first part.